# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, token

I have been reading up on this error on this forum but am not finding anything that is helping. The really odd thing is that I copied this from my instructor in a lecture but it will not run past the . Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Warner: iLab 1  Iteration and Summing Numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body style="font: 100% Ariel;">
    <h2>Iteration |Summing Numbers Between Two Integers |</h2><hr />
    <p>
       <script type="text/javascript">  

         var firstInt = parseInt(prompt("Enter an Integer from 1 and 4",""));
         document.write("Your first Entry: " +firstInt);
         var secondInt = parseInt(prompt("Enter an Integer from 6 and 9",""));
         document.write("<br> Your second Entry: "+secondInt+"<br>);
         var  sumNumbers = 0;
         for(var i=firstInt;  i<=secondInt;  i++)
         {
            sumNumbers += i;
         }
         document.write("<br>The answer is "+ sumNumbers);

       </script>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Read through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) about `document.write` - generally you'll want to avoid doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip...I'm just doing it how the instructor wants this done. I will definitely check this post out though.

Comment: The font name is "Arial." "Ariel" might not do what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close your double quote  4th line of script.

```
document.write("<br> Your second Entry: "+secondInt+"<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your closing quotation mark:

```
document.write("<br> Your second Entry: "+secondInt+"<br>);
```

Comment: If you're using a decent editor with syntax highlighting, the missing quote would be pretty obvious. I'd recommend finding a good editor - there are plenty of free ones.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quotes here:

```
 document.write("<br> Your second Entry: "+secondInt+"<br>);
```

Should be:

```
 document.write("<br> Your second Entry: "+secondInt+"<br>");
```

Hope this helps.